how to perform a click under 5mili seconds?[root or non-root]
Looking for the fastest method to perform clcik in android. Peferably 1mili sec per click, if possible.
I can manully perform so many clicks per second. So there gotta be a way to perform 10x more programatically, no?
Tried- input , sendevent. Also Motionevent.
Wasted times..., gaining nothing. In my device(virtual android in android), sendevent takes about 14s to perform 10 click. Horrible.
(I can click that much manully in 1~2 sec)
Read about modifying the getevent.c file from a comment but in my device i dont have any .c file.
Read this -> https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-client
Takes 100ms per click. But cant figure out how they did it.
[Cant use it since limited to phone, no involving of pc]
Read about uiAutomator but now im really in doubt. Couldnt get good result even with root method. Wasted so much time that dont have the slightest feeling to try it but anyway, i will probably try it tommorrow if i dont get an experts answer from this website.

Touch latency is configured when the ROM is created. Realize that sub 60 frames a second would depend on the digitizer and how much lag is desirable for debounce, i.e. how long should a touch last so that it is real vs hardware/user error.

Understood your first and last line's after i.e portion. So cant i do anything?

Not sure why you are trying to click that fast, but anything beyond human norms (perhaps to speed up testing) you'll run into physical digitizer limits or OS / app constraints as any app under test still needs to process said touch events/clicks.
